# Entity Framework 7 and Pluralization

Tags: entity-framework

Is there any way to force EF7 to use a Data Annotation field as the name a table when creating migrations?

For instance, I have the following entity:

```
[Table("Countries")]
public class Country
...
```

On my Context class:

```
public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

The migration file creates this table as:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Country",
...
```

It seems that EF7 is using the name of the object passed as template. I'd like to use either the Data Annotation or the name of the DbSet object instead.

I'm using SqlServer 2012 and EF 7.0.0-rc1-final (Core, Commands, and SqlServer).

Comment: In latest builds, changed to use the DbSet name by default!

Comment: I'm using 7.0.0-rc1-final (Core, Commands, and SqlServer).

Comment: I mean latest daily rc2 build